# Programmatically collapse/expand bs-collapse in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

Is there a method to collapse/expand angular-strap's collapse element in controller?

I want to collapse a `bs-collapse` element when its content is clicked. For that I need to control the state of a `bs-collapse` element. I expect a `$collapse` service like `bs-modal` has, however angular-strap does not provide that.

Comment: Isn't just a matter of specifying the index of the active panel? Just looking at [angular-strap examples](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/collapses), it seems that you can control just by doing `$scope.panels.activePanel = 2` - [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LP8XvDADwTP5krw3tS9Z?p=preview)